# Lombok and AspectJ with Sprint boot 2

Tags: lombok, aspects

I am trying to use Lombok along with AspectJ utilising spring boot.However, the ajc is not able to identify the getters/setters created by Lombok.I did try multiple attempts at it searching various solutions provided i.e generating delombok and then passing the byte code to ajc. one on them was from https://palesz.wordpress.com/2011/12/03/howto-maven-lombok-and-aspectj-together/

I am trying to run mvn test,would be thankful if anyone has come across similar situation and have a working solution.

Thanks

Comment: Post your code please.... and ask yourself the following question..."what happens if the link gets broken, the post removed... can others make sense of it and repeat the work?".